# URL Scheme for Linkedin

Tags: url, linkedin-api

I'm having an ios App. I'm able to open the linked native app from my ios App using the custom url scheme "linkedin://". But how to post a link to the linkedin native app through my ios App. Do we have any particular parameters for that?

What are the supported parameters for linkedin URL scheme?

Thanks, Thiagesh

Answer (score 8):

Linkedin has changed the scheme, now it works in this way:

```
linkedin://profile/[id]
```

Comment: It works using the id which you can see when you open a profile from the browser after _https://www.linkedin.com/in_ or _https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=_
The first one uses the "custom url" and the second the long and weird identifier.
With that scheme you can use both of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can jump to a profile with:

linkedin://#profile/9999

I just tested this on my iPhone 5. Works like a charm.

There's more conversation here, but not much content.
http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/link-open-linkedin-profile-browser-ios-linkedin-app

Answer (score 2):

If you get LinkedIn profile via [LinkedIn REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api), then you can find `publicProfileUrl` field in JSON:

```
{ 
  ...
  "publicProfileUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/eugene-brusov"
  ...
}
```

Then this line of code:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.linkedin.com/in/eugene-brusov"]];`

redirects you to target profile opened in the native LinkedIn app if it's installed or to the profile opened in iOS default browser.

Tested on iOS **10.0.2** and **11.0.1**.

Answer (score 0):

Working on iOS 8.3:

```
linkedin://profile?id=[id]
```

Take a look to: http://pureoxygenlabs.com/10-app-url-schemes-for-marketers/