# iOS Swift LinkedIn App URL Scheme is not working

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api, url-scheme

I want to open user linedIn profile(in linkedIn Native App) from my App.

I tried this but its just opening linekdin App but not profile page: [URL Scheme for Linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407170/url-scheme-for-linkedin)

I have added URLSchemes as well

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>linkedin</string>
</array>
```

This is my code

```
if let linkedinUrl = URL(string: "linkedin://profile?id=parmarvhv"),
   UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(linkedinUrl) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(linkedinUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

LinkedIn Web Url is this: https://www.linkedin.com/in/parmarvhv/

What is the correct way to open user profile?

Comment: It looks like you should have the URL be `linkedin://profile/parmarvhv` instead of  `linkedin://profile?id=parmarvhv`

Comment: @SpellChucker: It's not opening every profile, although it works in some cases

Answer (score 2):

This code works for `swift 5`:

Opening a LinkedIn page:

```
linkedin://company/binance
```

Opening a LinkedIn profile:

```
linkedin://profile/binance
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not documented. so you can't rely on it.

But, using `linkedin://in/{username}` works for me.