# How to open a deep link / universal link from LinkedIn?

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I created a React Native app with deep linking, or universal linking would be better named : I have a link https://share.my-app.com/id/12345, when it is clicked within a phone, there are three options:
-> the user has the app on the phone: it should open the app
-> the user doesn't have it: it opens the store
-> the user is not on a phone: it opens my website

It's working well quite everywhere, except on Facebook and LinkedIn on iOS. Both use an internal navigator when clicking on links, and even if the app is installed on the user's phone, it opens the store instead.

I saw this page for Facebook, I'll try right away and cross fingers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/metadata-reference/

But I didn't see anything for LinkedIn, except this video which you have to pay for, and I am not even sure it brings the right answer to my question.: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/learning-app-store-optimization-for-ios-and-android-apps/deep-linking-to-your-app

Does somebody knows how to make a deep link work in LinkedIn ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't supported by LinkedIn, there unfortunately isn't anything you can do.

Comment: I wonder why they have never implemented that. Because of possible high abuse of how it works or what?

Comment: @Denialos, my guess (obviously I don’t know for certain since I’m not LinkedIn) is that they just want to keep users inside their app. They even mask the URLs with a LinkedIn URL. Somewhat of a dark pattern in my opinion.

Comment: You mean, like, force users to use search instead of going directory a person's profile using a deep link? That's kind of shitty, even Meta's most apps support deep linking while LNKD claims itself to be an "innovative" company.

Comment: Well you can [deep link _from_ your app _into_ LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34498046/10752877). But, the question here is posting a link in LinkedIn and having that link work as expected as a deep link back into your app. LinkedIn uses an internal browser and URL masking - so it breaks deep links _out_ of the LinkedIn app. Essentially, they trap you in their app to view the links unless you copy the link and paste it into an external browser.